# how to update state in mockstore in ngrx unit testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx

I have a object defined as:

```js
obj:{
  name:"string",
  system:"string"
}
```

however I am trying to update the value in mockstore as:

```js
store.setState({
  name:"Rose",
  system:"Updated Dummy"
});
store.refreshState();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

but the value  is not updating. How can I update the value and then verify that it has been updated as a part of unit testing?

Comment: That should be working fine. Could you provide some more context, or maybe create a StackBlitz?

Answer (score 6):

`store.setState` updates the whole state. Therefore you need to use its feature name too to repeat the real store structure.

```js
const featureSelector = createFeatureSelector('FEATURE_NAME_IS_HERE');

store.setState({
  FEATURE_NAME_IS_HERE: { // <- adding the feature state.
    name:"Rose",
    system:"Updated Dummy"
  },
});
store.refreshState();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

If you use nested reducers - then you need to nest the object to de desired child.